# How can I check if component is enabled?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraInformation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string currentCameraState;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var components = new List<Component>();
        foreach (var component in GetComponents<Component>())
        {
            if (component != this)
            {
                var fullName = component.GetType().FullName;
                if (fullName.StartsWith("Cinemachine"))
                {
                    currentCameraState = component.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {

    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {

    }
}
```

At this line I want to assign the string the component status if it's enabled true or false.

Comment: Not all `Component` types in Unity have an enabled state. what specific components do you want to check for? it looks like the relevant Cinemachine types all derive from `MonoBehaviour`, which has an `enabled` property you can read, as the barest glance at the documentation would confirm. Did you try searching for `MonoBehaviour` instead of `Component`?

Answer (score 3):

A `MonoBehaviour` has an `enabled` property you can check. So:

```
currentCameraState = component.enabled ? "Cinemachine is enabled" : "Cinemachine is disabled";
```

Comment: Note that the `.enabled` property is not available on the `Component` type OP is using. So you would need to cast this so a more derived type.